# Trying to click a button on a simple modal window using capybara, cucumber and selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara

The website I am testing submits a form, once the form is submitted a simple modal window displays to thank the user with a close button.  I can't find a way to click that close button for some reason.

Here is the code for the modal window:

```
<div id="simplemodal-container" class="simplemodal-container" style="position: fixed; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 3px solid rgb(102, 102, 102); padding: 30px; width: 380px; height: 270px; z-index: 1002; left: 409px; top: 63.5px;">
    <div tabindex="-1" class="simplemodal-wrap" style="height: 100%; outline: 0px; width: 100%; overflow: visible;">
        <div id="leadconfirm" class="overlaycontent simplemodal-data" style="">
            <span class="popupheader">Talk to a</span>
            <div class="indent">
                <p class="bold">Thank you! You'll be hearing from us very soon.</p>
            </div>
        <div class="buttonRow">
            <input id="registrationclose" class="simplemodal-close btn submitBut" type="submit" value="Close" name="close">
        </div>
```

I have tried the following step definitions, the ones that are commented out I tried previously.

```
When /^I click on the xpath "([^\"]*)" button$/ do

find('button', :text => 'close')

#within("simplemodal-container")   { click_on button_name }

#find(:xpath,".//*[@id='registrationclose']").click_on button_id

# page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept

end

When /^I click on the "([^"]*)" button$/ do |button_value|
click_button button_value
end
```

Comment: Well how is the modal popup created? Is it a jQuery modal dialog? Is it a new window? A new tab?

Comment: It is a jQuery modal dialog that displays over the previous page.

Comment: Its just not clicking, below is what cucumber throws.  Given I click on the xpath "close" button # features/step_definitions/LeadForm.rb:9 Your block takes 0 arguments, but the Regexp matched 1 argument.  (Cucumber::ArityMismatchError) features/step_definitions/LeadForm.rb:9in /^I click on the xpath "<[^\"]*>" button$/' features